# How to get data form mysql database using php date?

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql **contact_details** table I've a column called **created_date**. I'm inserting **date and time** to this created_date column when I insert any new contact to that Table. **Date and time** is somethiing like this :

```
6/19/2013 18:25
6/19/2013 18:25
10/10/2014 17:25
```

Well, I've a Search form where 2 fields exist.

1) Date From.
2) Date To.

This 2 filed is pickup only Date (m/d/y) **not TIME**. Now I want to search data based on this 2 date. It's could be search Only **Date From** or **Date To** or **Both**.

1) Date From will be search **Date From** To **Today date**.
2) Date To will be search **All data** till **Date To**.
3) If both date exist then it's should return data between **2 date**

So, what I'm doing is following : But it's showing me wrong result. How do I fix this ?

```
if(!empty($ad_datefrom)){    
    $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN '$ad_datefrom' AND '$date' ";    
}

if(!empty($ad_dateto)){    
    $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN'$ad_dateto' AND '$date' ";   
}

if(!empty($ad_datefrom) && !empty($ad_dateto)){
    $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN '$ad_datefrom' AND '$ad_dateto' ";   
}
```

Note :

```
cd =  contact_details Table.
created_date = created_date Column of contact_details Table.  
$ad_datefrom =  Date From field.
$ad_dateto = Date To Field.
$date = current date (m/d/y)
```

Thank You :)

Comment: dude better you use `Timestamp` to save datetime in DB like   `20141121193620`. and then use `substring function` in yourquery for compairing date.

Comment: @SHAZ It's good idea. I will definitely use it but I've already 2,000 more data with date time structure. What Can I do now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ad_datefrom and $ad_dateto are in string format hence wont work with the between clause. Convert them using php date something like this:

```
 $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($ad_datefrom)) . "' AND '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date))."' ";
 $getSearch .= "AND cd.created_date BETWEEN '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($ad_dateto))."' AND '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date))."' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL want's datetime in format like '2014-12-24 23:59:59', to make it with `date()` function, do `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$timestamp)`